# PostgreSQL Table-Tracking Utility?

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to see a transactional history of operations that have been executed on one of my tables, and which user executed each operation. Does PostgreSQL offer any tools that allow that kind of historical lookup?

Comment: When you say operation are you talking DML or DDL? For DDL 9.3 will have some built ins http://www.depesz.com/2012/07/29/waiting-for-9-3-event-triggers/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe others can inform you if there are any good utilities that handle this for you, but I know triggers can be used to create audit logs of tables.  If you need more complex logic for how and what you want to audit you can also write procedural functions and incorporate them in your triggers. Example: [Postgres trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516421/postgres-trigger-function)

See this link: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus