# Trigger to update a different table

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, sql-update, plpgsql

Using Postgres 9.4, I have 2 tables `streams` and `comment_replies`. I am trying to do is update the `streams.comments` count each time a new `comment_replies` is inserted to keep track of the number of comments a particular stream has. I am not getting any errors but when I try to create a new comment it gets ignored.

This is how I am setting up my trigger. `stream_id` is a foreign key, so every `stream_id` will correspond to a `streams.id` which is the primary key of the `streams` table. I have been looking at this example: [Postgres trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516421/postgres-trigger-function), but haven't been able to get it to work.

```
CREATE TABLE comment_replies (
  id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  created_on timestamp without time zone,
  comments text,
  profile_id integer,
  stream_id integer
);
```

The trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Comment_Updates"()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$BEGIN
  update streams set streams.comments=streams.comments+1
  where streams.id=comment_replies_streamid;

END$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

And the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER comment_add
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON comment_replies
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE "Comment_Updates"();
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple errors. Try instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION comment_update()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   UPDATE streams s
   SET    streams.comments = s.comments + 1
-- SET    comments = COALESCE(s.comments, 0) + 1  -- if the column can be NULL
   WHERE  s.id = NEW.streamid;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER comment_add
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON comment_replies -- on UPDATE, too? Really?
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE comment_update();
```

You need to consider `DELETE` as well if that is possible. Also if `UPDATE` can change `stream_id`. But ***why*** increase the count for every `UPDATE`? This looks like another error to me.

- It's a syntax error to table-qualify the target column in the [`SET` clause of `UPDATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html).
- You need to [return `NEW` in a `BEFORE` trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html) unless you want to cancel the `INSERT` / `UPDATE`.
  ***Or*** you make it an `AFTER` trigger, which would work for this, too.
- You need to reference `NEW` for the `stream_id` of the current row (which is automatically visible inside the trigger function.
- If `streams.comments` can be NULL, use [`COALESCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL).

And rather use unquoted, legal, lower-case identifiers.

Comment: Thanks a lot that solved my issue, yeah I was completely lost and it will only be done on insert.